# How re-load data (not directly from an AJAX call) in Search Results table (triggered by a query from a Search Form) using DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am building a search form with a search results table. Using jQuery and DataTables.

**Possibly Overly-Long Preamble**

**Example (simplified) Form**:

```
<form id="frmSearchQuery">
  <input name="author" type="text">
  <input name="title" type="text">
  <button id="btnSubmitSearch" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

with

```
$("#frmSearchQuery").submit(onFormSubmit);
```

**Example (simplified) Table**:

```
<table id="tblSearchResults" style="display:none">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Author</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

(it is hidden initially)

**Example JavaScript**:

```
function onFormSubmit(event) {
  // validate and sanitise form data
  $.ajax({
    url: ...,
    method: "POST",
    data: ...,
    // painstaking but irrelevant details omitted for brevity
  }).done(onSearchQuerySuccess).fail(onSearchQueryFailure);
}

function onSearchQuerySuccess(resultsList) {
  $("#tblSearchResults").DataTable({
    ...
    data: resultsList,
    ...
  });
  $("#tblSearchResults").show();
}
```

So far so good. On searching, the results are returned from the server and shown in the table, which is now visible. The first time I search.

However, if I search again (without reloading the page), DataTable is already initialised and so  rendering the table fails.

If I were calling an AJAX endpoint from the table, I would be able to use `ajax.reload()`.

I tried initialising the DataTable once at the beginning.

```
function initTable() {
  $tblSearchResults = $("#tblSearchResults").DataTable({
    ...
    data: resultsList,
    ...
  });
}
```

using a page-global variable for the resultsList. Initialising it with

```
resultsList = [];
```

at the top of the page, and updating the same list (as opposed to reassigning it) in `onSearchQuerySuccess`.

```
function onSearchQuerySuccess(queryResults) {
  resultsList.push.apply(queryResults);
  $tblSearchResults.rows().invalidate().draw();
}
```

But this fails to re-render the table with new data. The resultsList Array is definitely getting appended to.

**My Actual Question**

This scenario cannot be new to this well-established technology stack.

Search form calls API to get search results. Search results are rendered in a DataTable. Doing the search again results in updated search results. Need to be updated in the table.

Maybe I am not using the appropriate terms (I am not a Javascript/JQuery developer), but I found precious little demonstrating how this should be done.

Comment: Can't u just destroy the Datatable before you initialize it(if it already set)?

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand why you're not using jQuery DataTable's Ajax functionality: **[Ajax sourced data](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html)**. In case you don't want to go for that route, have you read this **[Warning: Cannot reinitialize DataTable](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3)** by chance?